# React native useEffect render problem when trying to get user's auth state firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, use-effect

I have a problem with useEffect. When I try to get the auth state of the user after the `onAuthStateChanged`, the number of calls in the useEffect is insanely high. Sometimes it gives this error too:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

[This is the amount of logs after the user login/registers and logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9jpz.png). Maybe i'm not understanding well how useEffect works. Here is the code which uses useEffect:

```js
useEffect(async () => {
    let isCancelled = false;
    await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user && !isCancelled) {
          await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data()
            console.log(document.data())
            setUser(userData);
            setIsSignedIn(true);
            setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false);
            alert(error)
          });
        }else{
          console.log('user does not exist')
          setIsSignedIn(false);
          setLoading(false);
        }
    });
    return () => {
      isCancelled = true;
    }
  }, []);
```

[This is the image of it. Maybe it's more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCkBr.png)

Answer (score 2):

In general, each `useEffect` should be in charge of one task. Also, the current method of using `isCancelled` is not actually cleaning up the listeners like they should.

For react, you should try to use real time updates where possible. You'll also benefit from being able to easily detach the listeners.

Here's a scaffold that you can work from.

```
// Set up a state variable to contain the user's info
// If a user is already logged in and validated, user is immediately
// set to their User object, otherwise show loading icon while we check
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => firebase.auth().currentUser || undefined);
const userLoading = user === undefined;
const isSignedIn = !!user;

// Set up a state variable to contain the user's data
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(undefined);

// Set up a state variable to contain whether this component is loading
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

// effect to track user state and update `user` for any changes
// onAuthStateChanged returns its own cleanup function
useEffect(() => firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUser), []); // <- don't rerun

// effect to navigate to login
useEffect(() => {
  if (user === null) {
    // user is signed out
    navigation.navigate('login');
  }
}, [user]); // <- rerun when user changes

useEffect(async () => {
  if (!isSignedIn) return; // you could write this as `userLoading || !isSignedIn`, but it's redundant

  return firebase.firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .onSnapshot({ // <- onSnapshot() returns its own cleanup function
      next(docSnapshot) {
        const userData = docSnapshot.data();
        setUserData(userData);
      },
      error(err) {
        console.error(err);
        alert(err);
      }
    });
}, [user]); // <- rerun when user changes
```

As a bit of learning project, consider making it into a `Context` or create your own `useAuth` function where you can pull out the user's data, the user object and the loading states.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm trying to make it work but i can't

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Just saying it's not working doesn't give enough information.

Comment: When i press the register button, the user gets registered and his info gets saved in the Authentication field in firebase but the user data don't on firestore so when the auth state of the user changes after the registration, he tries to go to HomeScreen without any data. Its likely that i'm using useEffect in a wrong manner. If you want i can edit my question, adding the full code of the navigation and the registration one

Comment: @tedofrenci The code here exclusively handles reading the data in after a user has logged in/completed registration as you requested & included in your question. This code doesn't handle any navigation, etc after a user has signed in as you didn't ask about that. If you are having trouble with sign-in flow after applying this fix, ask a new question with the new code and problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
useEffect(async () => {
    let isCancelled = false;
    const unsubscribe = await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
       ........ 
    });
    return () => {
      // cleanup 
     unsubscribe() 
      isCancelled = true;
    }
  }, []);
```

let me know if it works for youb